# post a diff between svn branch and a tag on review board

Tags: svn, review-board

I want to post an SVN diff to the review board; the diff is generated between the branch HEAD and the base tag.

I used this command to generate the diff file :

`svn diff https:/path/to/branch/head https:/path/to/tag`

note that

- i tried to use `rbt diff revision1:revision2` command to generate the diff. I have a problem that review board only accepts revision range within the branch commits only (not accepting revision from tags).
- i tried to diff using the `svn diff` command then upload the file using `rbt post --diff-filename` but the command returned with an error requiring a base directory; i added the base dir to to be the root using `rbt post --basedir https:/path/to/root` ; the review boards accept but shows the diff on the web page like a diff between `https:/path/to/root/branches/featureName/path/to/changed/files` and `https:/path/to/root/path/to/changed/files` without showing that the diff is between branch and a tag like `https:/path/to/root/tag/path/to/changed/files`.

is there any way to do such job ?

Comment: Were you able to generate required diff file using SVN diff? I think you have only problem in uploading the same to review-board, is that right?

Comment: yes, i am able to generate diff file using SVN diff. when trying to upload the diff file to review-board but error messages appeared
error message example:
_/path/to/folder/branches/development/feature/branches/development/feature/path/to/file.py: The file was not found in the repository. (HTTP 400, API Error 207)_
as you can see the review board repeat the path to branch twice which is no correct; it is expected to have a path like _/path/to/folder/branches/development/feature/path/to/file.py_
somehow a problem between SVN diff file and review-board parsing; which i don't know
thanks @Sukuva

Comment: Can you try generating diff from the root of the repository rather than individual file? The root should be same as your review board base url

Comment: One thing you have to make sure is the "base path" between the top of the repository and the path in which the diffs were generated

Comment: i hope the ticket is more clear after editing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can post such a diff with the [RBTools](https://www.reviewboard.org/downloads/rbtools/) `post` command.

Say, for example, your Subversion repository is registered with following URL at review board:

```
http://svn.example.org/foo/base/group
```

(where `foo` is noise and `base` is the base of your repository)

Then let's assume that we have two tags

```
http://svn.example.org/foo/base/group/module/tag/abc1
http://svn.example.org/foo/base/group/module/tag/abc2
```

where `abc2` is based on `abc1` and introduces some changes.

To create a review request for those changes, first, we make a diff with Subversion:

```
base=http://svn.example.org/foo/base/group
svn diff $base/module/tag/abc1 $base/module/tag/abc2 \
  > --patch-compatible > change_xyz.diff
```

We can post the diff with `rbt post`, but for that, we need a Subversion working directory. An empty one is sufficient:

```
svn co --depth=empty $base
cd group
```

The `rbt` command needs some configuration, to simplify things username/password can also be stored in a run control file, e.g.:

```
cat > .reviewboardrc <<EOF
REVIEWBOARD_URL = 'http://reviewboard.example.org/'
REPOSITORY = 'somerepo'
PASSWORD = 'einsfueralles'
USERNAME = 'juser'
EOF
```

When posting the diff the `rbt` resolves the relative paths in the diff file against the working directory, thus we have to add missing parts with the `--basedir` option:

```
rbt post --diff-filename ../change_xyz.diff --basedir module/tag
```

If everything works ok, `rbt` uploads the diff and the referenced files to a new draft and prints the new URLs, e.g.:

```
http://reviewboard.example.org/r/23/
http://reviewboard.example.org/r/23/diff/
```

The draft can then be edited and finally published via the web UI. The `rbt post` command also has several options to add additional data (e.g. `--summary`, `--description`) and/or directly publish it (cf. `--publish`).

Comment: I have already did what you tell above, but the problem resides in the URL preview in the review board
I can see the URLs shown like that : 
[http://svn.example.org/foo/base/group/module/tag/abc1]
that was for the first base part (right hand side in the diff preview)
[http://svn.example.org/foo/base/abc2]
as you can see the left hand sided URL in the diff preview doesn't have the full URL

Comment: @MuhammadYusuf, as-is, my answer only works for SVN URLs where just the last component is different - as in `http://example.org/foo/tag/abc1` and `http://example.org/foo/tag/abc2`