# Review board - post commit review from separate revisions

Tags: svn, review-board, rbtools

I am doing a proof of concept of review-board for a team of around 20 developers. We currently send code reviews using emails and manual screenshot of post commit changes (SVN) and I hope we can move away from that.

The challenge that I am facing is that developers check in code changes usually multiple times. A single functionality for instance could have 10 separate revisions or more. The ticket number is saved into the revision message each time. Most code changes happen in a single main branch.

In order to perform a code review (current approach) a developer will go to tortoise SVN then do a search on the ticket number, then select the earliest and latest revisions and click "compare revisions", then take screenshots.

I tried review board and I am very impressed overall. however I could not find a way to do something similar to what we do currently? Using the web approach I am only able post a review for a single revision.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the web approach, use the utility [rbt](https://www.reviewboard.org/downloads/rbtools/) to post the reviews. Take a look at the [rbt post documentation](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/rbtools/dev/rbt/commands/post/).

Once you have the earliest revision (rev1) and the latest revision(rev2) corresponding to the ticket, post a review with

```
rbt post <options> rev1:rev2
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem with this however is that unrelated code changes that are in the revision list will be also included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `svn diff` to generate a diff like you do in tortoise:

```
svn diff http://path/to/trunk@rev1 http://path/to/trunk@rev2 \
    --patch-compatible > featurex.diff
```

And that diff can then directly be posted with `rbt post`:

```
rbt post --diff-filename featurex.diff
```

The post command must be executed in the working copy of `http://path/to/trunk` - which may also be empty (cf `svn co --depth=empty ...`).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36800535/427158 for steps how to create a review request for a complete branch.